# ROS melodic - CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/grid_map_cv/cmake/grid_map_cvConfig.cmake:113 (message):

Tags: opencv, cmake

Trying to build some ROS packages, but keep saying this error. Opencv is installed and it does have the OpenCV file in the path indicated. I have been trying to solve this issue for so long. Thank you for your help!

Errors << ticobot_occupancy_grid:cmake /home/nvidia/catkin_ws/logs/ticobot_occupancy_grid/build.cmake.010.log
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/grid_map_cv/cmake/grid_map_cvConfig.cmake:113 (message):
Project 'grid_map_cv' specifies '/usr/include/opencv ' as an include dir,
which is not found. It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
'${{prefix}}//usr/include/opencv '. Check the issue tracker
'http://github.com/anybotics/grid_map/issues' and consider creating a
ticket if the problem has not been reported yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/melodic/share/grid_map_ros/cmake/grid_map_rosConfig.cmake:197 (find_package)
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (find_package)

Answer (score 0):

In /opt/ros/melodic/share/grid_map_cv/cmake/grid_map_cvConfig.cmake

Change

if(NOT "include;/usr/include;/usr/include/opencv " STREQUAL " ")

set(grid_map_cv_INCLUDE_DIRS "")

set(_include_dirs "include;/usr/include;/usr/include/opencv")

To

if(NOT "include;/usr/include;/usr/include/opencv " STREQUAL " ")

set(grid_map_cv_INCLUDE_DIRS " include;/usr/include;/usr/include/opencv ")

set(_include_dirs "include;/usr/include;/usr/include/opencv")

Solved my problem!